# Opening zoom meetings from Java

Tags: java, terminal, zoom-sdk

I'm trying to create a Java application which will be able to open (join) Zoom meetings.

You can open zoom meetings via terminal if you explicitly have id and password, with command: `open zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=ID&pwd=PASSWORD`, you can use this command in Java as well.

However, sometimes you don't own the id and password explicitly, you have some strange link, with no way to evaluate their id and pass. Though, if you paste this strange link in say Google Chrome, it will offer you to launch Zoom application and then you will join the meeting.

I can do this with Java, I can make default browser go to some link, but I don't want that, I don't want to go through browser, I want it directly.

Is there any way to open Zoom meeting directly from Java with just strange link? (No id and pass explicitly) As Google chrome does it, it has the link and it's able to open the meeting.

Well, if I could open it via terminal, I would do it with Java as well. I tried `curl`, but it's just getting me the html response only, maybe expected.

By the way, if needed, I'm using MacOS Monterey with zsh.

Comment: This can help https://gist.github.com/brycemcd/04092405cbc663ee7ea48b933e40844e

Comment: @ArthurKlezovich I guess they use this kind of links: `zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=ID&pwd=PASSWORD`, I don't think it works for any kind of zoom link.

Comment: Have you checked out the Zoom API? https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/using-zoom-apis

Comment: > you have some strange link, with no way to evaluate their id and pass

Can you provide an example of such link ?

Comment: @ArthurKlezovich I've rechecked now and it seems like `https://zoom.us/j/ID?pwd=PASSWORD` is the pattern of the link. On some forum in the past I saw that the links are different. I couldn't find now that it's anything else than the one above. Though, I want to be sure, that's why I'm looking for more general way. Not to rely on some pattern which may change in the future.